# Fix back button issue on load more pagination style

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination, infinite-scroll

**HTML**

```
<div class="moreButton">
        <a class="more" id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($page);?>">More</a>
</div>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(function(){
    $('.more').live('click', function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('id');      //get the last id

        $.ajax({
            type    : 'GET',
            url     : 'functionality/js/paginate.php',
            data    : { page : page, per_page : per_page, last_page : last_page },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.more').html(img);
                if(history.pushState){
                   history.pushState(null, null, '#' + page);
                }else{
                   location.hash = '#' + page;
                }
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('.more').remove();
                $('.main-content').append(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I've implemented a `load_more` style of pagination. The problem here is the usual for infinite scrolls, when a user clicks a post and comes back with back button, he/she should get the previous number of loaded posts, but only initial posts are loaded. I'm trying to integrate the `history.pushState` functionality based on what I found googling, but doesn't seem to get it working. What am I missing here?

Comment: What exactly isn't working about it? I just opened the dev console and typed `history.pushState(null, null, "/page/xyz")` in Chrome and it changed the URL while keeping me on the same page.

Comment: it does changes the `url`, the problem is when the user clicks a post and comes back with the browser back button. The number of posts is not loaded automatically.

Comment: Should `location.hash = '/page/' + page;` include `/page/` ?

Comment: @guest271314 not necessarily.

Comment: @vephelp Not certain interpret Question correctly ; user click `.more` , what is expected result ? user click browser "back" button , what is expected result ?

Comment: @guest271314, initially page has 10 posts. When user clicks `.more` it loads 5 more on same page without refreshing. Then lests say the user clicks on the 13th post from those 15 posts, 13th post opens. Then user clicks back button to see total 15 posts but then only 10 posts are loaded. That is what I'm trying to fix, it should load the 5 posts as well loaded using the `.more` button.

Comment: @vephelp Given scenario; if , a) ten posts initially loaded , b) user clicks "more" , five additional posts loaded. "back" button would load initial a) 10 posts. Why would user expect back button to load fifteen posts - if they clicked "back" while at page containing fifteen posts ? Would that not be similar to "reload" ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two key parts to saving states using browser history. The `pushState` function allows you to add to the history stack (essentially like going to a new page). It also allows you to store a javascript object as the "state". This will come in handy when the state is "popped" off the stack (e.g. the browser's "back" button is pressed).

Browsers throw a `popstate` event which you can use to determine if the browser is going back to a previous state. You can access it with [`window.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate). To watch for a hash change you can use [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange).

```js
if ("onpopstate" in window) {
    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
        if (event.state && event.state.pageID) {
            fetchData(event.state.pageID);
        }
    };
}

if ("onhashchange" in window) {
    window.onhashchange = function () {
        if (location.hash) {
            fetchData(location.hash.substr(1));
        }
    };
}

function fetchData(pageID) {
    // Load some content
}

function saveState(pageID) {
    if (history.pushState) {
        history.pushState({ pageID: pageID }, null, "/page/" + pageID);
    } else {
        location.hash = pageID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should `location.hash = '/page/' + pageID;`  include `/page/` ?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, I was just going off OP's example. I didn't see he changed it.

Comment: _"It doesn't really matter,"_ ? To some, everything might matter; to others nothing might matter; what "matters" is subjective. Appear to "matter" to OP, or perhaps Question would not be asked; would already be solved by OP ? Tried `location.hash` at `console` ?

Comment: @guest271314, what I meant by "doesn't matter" is that you can do it either way so it's just up to preference. "#/page/1" is a perfectly valid hash, as is "#1". For example, you could have "#/abc/1" and "#/xyz/1" serve two different contents. Look at how projects like Durandal or Angular handle routing. Setting `location.hash = "/page/1"` will make it so that `location.hash` returns `"#/page/1"`. This works fine in Chrome's console.  Regardless, I've changed my question to reflect OP's changes to just use `pageID` for the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to define a function to check hash update as if hash updates(User clicks on back/forward button) it should update data of the page according to URL.